# Increasing performance on a 90+ seconds google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, show-hide

I am building a script in google apps, for a spreadsheet, that lets me hide rows where column H contains an astrisk (*). The spreadsheet is currently 700+ rows, and when i run the script it takes about 90 seconds before it is done and i can see the results. Aint' nobody got time for dat, so i am trying to make it more efficient.

This is what the pieced together code looks like, and i have no clue as to how to rewrite it to be faster. I got the inspiration here; [Hide Rows in a Google Spreadsheet based on first Character in a cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16209724/hide-rows-in-a-google-spreadsheet-based-on-first-character-in-a-cell?rq=1)

```
/**
 * Hides rows where H = Astrisk, Unhides where H != Astrisk
 */
function updateProgram() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Week 1-4");
  var data = sheet.getRange('H:H').getValues();

//iterate over all rows
  for(var i=0; i< data.length; i++){
    //compare first character, if asterisk, then hide row
    if(data[i][0].charAt(0) == '*'){
      sheet.hideRows(i+1);
    } else sheet.showRows(i+1);
  }
}
```

It is currently running through all rows and executing functions on a single condition and executing a function on every single row. I have thought about this for a possible solution;

- If H = * || row is showing Then hide
- If H != * || row is hidden Then show
- Otherwise do nothing

So only rows that need hiding/showing gets it.

Thank you for taking your time to read this - if you can help me, it will be much appreciated!

UPDATE;

I figured out a way to group the rows, showing and hiding a number of rows dependent on a value. The code now looks like this and takes 10 seconds to run.

This is some of my first self-written code, so any feedback is welcome!

```
function updateProgramWeek1to4() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var s = ss.getSheetByName("Week 1-4");
var row = s.getRange('G:G').getValues();
var maxRows = s.getMaxRows();

s.showRows(1, maxRows);

for(var i=0; i< row.length; i++){
   if(row[i] == '0'){
     s.hideRows(i+1, 11);
   } 
     else if(row[i] == '1'){
     s.hideRows(i+3, 9);
   } 
     else if(row[i] == '2'){
     s.hideRows(i+4, 8);   
   } 
     else if(row[i] == '3'){
     s.hideRows(i+5, 7);
   } 
     else if(row[i] == '4'){
     s.hideRows(i+6, 6);   
   } 
     else if(row[i] == '5'){
     s.hideRows(i+7, 5);
   } 
     else if(row[i] == '6'){
     s.hideRows(i+8, 4);
   } 
     else if(row[i] == '7'){
     s.hideRows(i+9, 3);
   } 
     else if(row[i] == '8'){
     s.hideRows(i+10, 2);
   } 
     else if(row[i] == '9'){
     s.hideRows(i+11, 1);
   } 
     else if(row[i] == '10'){
     s.hideRows(i+12);  
   }
     else if(row[i] == '11'){
     s.hideRows(i+1);  
   }
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make it much faster by using the second param in sheet.hideRows/showRows which tell it how many to process. You need to change your loop and remember how many rows have the same state. When the state changes you show/hide in batch.

Comment: See example code for how to do that: https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/docs/1qHnz9qtb18/vTKtearoBgAJ

Answer (score 2):

I created a modified version of this script.

[HERE](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DGDrRbUWG6FRi1gSRCT-GgFgEUuEpDWKMxIEDSQBw2c/edit?usp=sharing) is a demo spreadsheet. Create your own copy. It hides up to 500 rows at once. The idea is similar to paying cash using minimum number of paper bills. The script reads the numbers 1, 5, 10, 50, 100 and 500 from a column on the sheet and hides that many rows at once. Each block of consecutive rows is calculated separately. That means if you want some rows in the middle to be visible, the hidden rows before or after those are processed equally fast. Let's say you have some visible rows, then 63 hidden rows, then some visible rows again, then 756 hidden rows. The 63 rows will be processed in 5 steps as 50+10+1+1+1. The 756 rows are processed in 6 steps as 500+100+100+50+5+1.

Credit goes to user2845885 above for writing and sharing the initial version of the code. Here is my modified version:

```
function hideRows() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var s = ss.getSheetByName("Demo sheet"); // Enter sheet name
var row = s.getRange('B:B').getValues(); // Enter column letter that has the numbers 500, 100, 50, 10, 5, 1

s.showRows(1, s.getMaxRows());

for(var i=0; i< row.length; i++){ 
if(row[i] == '500') { s.hideRows(i+1, 500); }
else if(row[i] == '100'){ s.hideRows(i+1, 100); }
else if(row[i] == '50'){ s.hideRows(i+1, 50); }
else if(row[i] == '10'){ s.hideRows(i+1, 10); }
else if(row[i] == '5'){ s.hideRows(i+1, 5); }
else if(row[i] == '1'){ s.hideRows(i+1, 1); } } }
```

I don't understand much about coding but I'm fairly good with formulas. However, surprisingly writing the formula for the numbers column was much harder than the script. Here is the tricky part: let's say the next number in the numbers column is 10, meaning that the script will hide 10 rows at once. This works only if the next 9 rows after 10 don't contain any of the numbers the script is looking for. Therefore the formula was very tricky. Here is how to create the numbers column: Assuming in column A starting from A2, it says "Hide" in rows you want to hide and visible rows are blank. Enter this formula to cell B2 and copy down:

```
=IF(OR(A2="",
SUM($B1:INDEX(B$1:B1,IF(row()-499<1,1,row()-499)))>=500,
SUM($B1:INDEX(B$1:B1,IF(row()-99<1,1,row()-99)))>=100,
SUM($B1:INDEX(B$1:B1,IF(row()-49<1,1,row()-49)))>=50,
SUM($B1:INDEX(B$1:B1,IF(row()-9<1,1,row()-9)))>=10,
SUM($B1:INDEX(B$1:B1,IF(row()-4<1,1,row()-4)))>=5),
"",
IF(ArrayFormula(MATCH(FALSE,A2:A=A2,0)-1)>=500,500,
IF(ArrayFormula(MATCH(FALSE,A2:A=A2,0)-1)>=100,100,
IF(ArrayFormula(MATCH(FALSE,A2:A=A2,0)-1)>=50,50,
IF(ArrayFormula(MATCH(FALSE,A2:A=A2,0)-1)>=10,10,
IF(ArrayFormula(MATCH(FALSE,A2:A=A2,0)-1)>=5,5,
IF(ArrayFormula(MATCH(FALSE,A2:A=A2,0)-1)<5,1)))))))
```